# Do i need to include additional image size for iPhone X, for example 4x images

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I mostly use pdfs for vectors so for most of my images this is not an issue. For non vector png's do I need to include 4x images or any additional images for the new iPhone X super retina screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone X has a high-resolution display with a scale factor of @3x.